# Unit tests for ViewModel classes that open dialog windows

Tags: .net, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, dialog

I'm using the MVVM pattern in my WPF application. At least for major views, but not for simple dialogs. One of those dialogs for example contains a window title, action label, TextBox, another CheckBox and ok/cancel buttons. Such dialogs are used in a number of ViewModel commands to ask the user, where to copy that thing, or how to do it exactly. The command method then creates an instance of that window, calls ShowDialog() and you probably know the rest. It shows the window, then stops and waits for the user to close it.

Now I'm beginning to look into unit tests for my ViewModel classes as things are getting more complex and I'd like to monitor when I break something else... The problem is, the dialog windows can't be unit-tested... So I need a way to provide that user input through my unit test code automatically and with no manual intervention.

Any idea how to solve that problem without adding too much other complexity to the application?

Comment: Well, depending on your definition of "too much complexity", you could try to encapsulate your dialog calling logic into a `IDialogService` and then do the typical dependency injection like you would for other services.

Comment: Would that interface provide a method for each dialog in the application, or should I use one interface per dialog? I'm not using DI yet and I'm not sure what else it could be useful for.

Comment: With IDialogService you may need to mock the service in the testing. If you have an event (for each different messagebox or dialog, if this is more then you need to redesign the UI)in VM e.g. OnError which is subscribed by the View to show the dialog/messagebox. Raise the event whenever you want to show the dialog from viewmodel.